# When running custom container in Kubeflow, how to pass arguments to the container?

Tags: containers, kubeflow, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I created a container image, and want to run it as part of my Kubeflow pipeline.

I tested the image locally and have no problem running it:

```
docker run $IMAGE_URI --my_argument 28
```

I tried running it in Kubeflow using pre-built component, [CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp][1], but failed. It seems that the problem is with the arguments, since it had no problem when hard-coded the argument value in the Python code.  How do I correctly pass the argument in this component? Thanks.

```
import kfp
from kfp.v2 import compiler
from kfp.v2.dsl import component
from kfp.v2.google import experimental
from kfp.v2.google.client import AIPlatformClient
from google_cloud_pipeline_components import aiplatform as gcc_aip

@kfp.dsl.pipeline(name=pipeline_name, pipeline_root='gs://a-gcs-bucket')
def pipeline():
    
    subclass_training_job_run_op = gcc_aip.CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp(
        project=project_id, 
        display_name=model_display_name,
        container_uri=subclass_container_uri,
        args=["--my_argument", 28],
        staging_bucket=staging_bucket,
        base_output_dir=base_output_uri,
        #dataset=dataset_create_op.outputs["dataset"]
    )

Thank you!


  [1]: https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-0.1.4/google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.html#google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.CustomContainerTrainingJobRunOp
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved:

```
args=["--my_argument", "28"]
```